How to rewrite the axiom "there is a set" into FOL formula?
I wonder how to rewrite the set-theory axiom "there exists a set" into FOL formula. Literally, the sentence can be translated to $\exists \, x$, which is not a FOL formula. So, it would be like $\exists \, x \, (x \, \text{is a set})$. But which formula corresponds to "$x$ is a set"? I see some books use $\exists \, x \, x=x$ to represent this axiom, but I'm not clear why the formula $x=x$ corresponds to "$x$ is a set".

If you have in mind a first-order theory in which not everything is a set, over what does it quantify? if it's classes, use $\exists x\exists y(x\in y)$.

"X is a Set" is not a formula in LST. Set's are primitive, undefined terms in Set Theory, there is no definition of a set. Intuitively, all the elements in our domain of discourse are sets, so if it exits, it is a set. But, that is not a formally defined notion.

For what it is worth, I use a Set predicate. My axioms of set theory apply only to objects that are declared to be sets. "$Set(x)$" is taken to mean that x is a set. The axiom of pairwise union, for example, is $\forall a: \forall b: [Set(a) \land Set(b) \implies \exists c: [Set(c) \land \forall d: [d\in c \iff d\in a \lor d\in b]]]$

To indicate that there exists a set, I can write: $\exists x: Set(x)$ or simply $Set(x)$.
